# cv2.VideoWriter: Asks for a tuple as Size argument, then rejects it

Tags: python, video-processing, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 4.0 and Python 3.7 to create a timelapse video.

When constructing a VideoWriter object, the documentation says the Size argument should be a tuple.

When I give it a tuple it rejects it. When I try to replace it with something else, it won't accept it because it says the argument isn't a tuple.

When Size not a tuple:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', 1482049860, 30, height, width)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

When I changed Size to a tuple:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', 1482049860, 30, (height, width))
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

I just want to create a simple cv2.VideoWriter object.

Comment: What are the exact values of `height` and `width`? The only way I can reproduce this is when they are floating point values. They should be integers. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DanMašek the code was this:

    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

but without 'int' before the cap.get. I added the 'int' and now it works. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to take the height and width from an uploaded video using:

```
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```

I changed it to:

```
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

Now I don't get that error. It doesn't work yet as a whole, but that particular error isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same situation, here is my solution:

It seems like `cv2.VideoWriter()` tend to "drop" the argument that has the wrong type. In my case I used `pathlib.Path` for the first output file name argument,like:

```
p=Path('project.avi')

out = cv2.VideoWriter(p, 1482049860, 30, frameSize=(height, width))
```

But `cv2.VideoWriter()` only accepts str, so it "dropped" the p, and it received:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(1482049860, 30, frameSize=(height, width))
```

Then `(height, width)` is actually at the `fps` position, it requires real but gets tuple

So I suggest you check every argument to make sure they have the right type.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to opencv v4.1.0. Not seeing that issue there.

Else try:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', 1482049860, 30, frameSize=(height, width))
```

Comment: No point, this makes no difference, you just didn't reproduce the actual scenario on OP's end since they didn't provide a [mcve].